# How to turn off ‘tab’ highlighting in go buffers?

Tags: emacs, go

I’ve just started writing Go programs in Emacs. How can I turn off tabs highlighting in go-mode buffers? I use «whitespace» for whitespace chars highlighting. Go btw is the only mode where I don’t want tabs highlighted since tabs are standard formatting in Go.

Sincerely, Pavel.

Comment: If you want to keep some of the whitespace highlighting, the variable `whitespace-style` can be adjusted to include only those elements you wish to highlight.  To see the options available for that variable, type `M-x describe-variable RET whitespace-style RET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, you're doing something like

```
(require 'whitespace)
(global-whitespace-mode t)
```

right? You can disable `whitespace-mode` for `go-mode` with

```
(setq whitespace-global-modes '(not go-mode))
```

There is a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/only-enable-whitespace-mode-in-certain-buffers) on emacs stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)
        (setq whitespace-style '(face empty trailing lines-tail))
        (setq tab-width 4)
        (setq indent-tabs-mode 1)))
```

Worked a bit better for me. Leaves whitespace-mode on but doesn't highlight tabs. Also runs go fmt before save and sets tab width to 4. I'm using prelude.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
(whitespace-toggle-options '(tabs)))
```

To your go-mode hook e.g

```
(use-package go-mode
  :preface
  (defun go-mode-config ()
    (whitespace-toggle-options '(tabs)))
  :config
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (go-mode-config))))
```

Taken from [prelue go config](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/bb152ad383ad6556d4cac1128f4f0d8fb32d7baf/modules/prelude-go.el#L66)